# Issue while formatting date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to format the following value 01/08/2020

```
Dim value1 as string  = '01/08/2020'

Response.Write(Format(CDate(value1),"yyyy-MMM-dd"))
```

The result returned as 2020-Jan-08 instead of 2020-Aug-01

Comment: If it's in your source code, declare it as a `DateTime` value in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier method for formatting dates. Try this:

```
Response.Write(DateTime.ParseExact(value1, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"))
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings for the various possible date formats.

Answer (score 0):

Out of caution I'd do this

```
    Dim value1 As String = "1/8/2020" '
    Dim d As Date
    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(value1, "d/M/yyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
        Dim s As String = d.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd")
        Response.Write(s)
    Else
        Stop 'error placeholder
    End If
```

You'll need to add code where the Stop is in case of error in the parse.